# Catch props data on component change in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created  a modal box component and passing data to it using props. in this component I want to catch this props data into a vue `data()` method only when the modal is opened(showed). How can I do that?

One method I did which worked is using `updated()` event like below code but realized it runs globally an not just on component update.

```
export default {
  props: ['widget_data'],

  data() {
    return {
      new_data: {},
    }
  },

  methods: {
    hideMe() {
      this.$emit('closeClicked')
    },
    saveMe() {
      this.$emit('saveClicked')
    },
  },

  updated() {
    this.new_data = this.widget_data
  },
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by _"`updated()` runs globally"_ but you could also try adding a watcher for `widget_data`?

Comment: You can use watch. Detect open modal and then when happened modal you can update data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass the props to vue watchers

```
 watch: {
   widget_data: function (val) {
     //here you can put logic to save updated value to data method
   }
 }
```